# How can I update my Kanban board's filter to ignore closed XRAY Test issues?

Tags: jira, jira-agile, kanban, jira-xray, jira-filter

I have a Kanban board and I see all XRAY Test issues in Open issues navigator even though they are closed. The Open issues are using a filter to pick issues where Resolution is unresolved and all XRAY issues has Resolution as UnResolved as the workflow doesn't mandate picking up a resolution for the XRAY Issues. Can anyone help how to update Kanban board - Open issues filter to ignore Closed issues or how to update resolution for XRAY Issues?

Created a filter and tried to use it on Kanban board but the board doesn't let me update the open issues filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Jira to think of an issue as being closed it needs to have something in the RESOLUTION field. The status of the issue doesn't matter, even if it is CLOSED or DONE.

You could use [batch update](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/editing-multiple-issues-at-the-same-time-939938937.html) on all closed XRAY Test issues and give them a resolution value. I would also suggest [modifying the workflow to set a resolution value](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/jira-issues-need-a-resolution-826873869.html) when an XRAY Test issue is transitioned to CLOSED.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Boards -> Boards Settings -> Edit filter query ->  `project = XXX AND issuetype not in (Precondition,Test,"Test Execution","Test Plan","Test Set","Sub Test Execution")` or just add the `AND issuetype not in (Precondition,Test,"Test Execution","Test Plan","Test Set","Sub Test Execution")`  to your existing filter.

[Official Documentation](https://docs.getxray.app/display/ProductKB/%5BXray+Cloud%5D+How+to+remove+any+Xray+Issue+Type+from+your+Boards)

Comment: Thank you, I don't want to ignore the XRAY Issue types as they are also valid when open,

Comment: @AnishaR This is just an example, customize this query as you wish. ```AND issuetype not in (Precondition,Test,"Test Execution","Test Plan","Test Set","Sub Test Execution") AND status NOT IN ('whatever') ```